# How to force Sitecore MVC to render height and width attributes on image tag

Tags: image, model-view-controller, sitecore

When using Web forms in sitecore an img tag is rendered with the Height and Width attributes e.g.

```
<img src="~/media/Images/example.jpg" alt="" width="245" height="245">
```

When using Sitecore MVC with a view rendering, the  tag is rendered as

```
<img src="/~/media/Images/example.png?h=300&amp;la=en&amp;w=316" alt="">
```

How can I make Sitecore MVC render the  tag with the Width and Height attributes as per web forms?

Comment: Can you please share code how you are rendering image in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are from `FieldRenderer` and `sc:image`. so, in this case, you have to remove it.

This page will help you, http://www.mikkelhm.dk/archive/removing-width-and-height-tags-from-fieldrenderer-and-scimage/

Comment: the question is how to "make Sitecore MVC render the tag with the Width and Height attributes as per web forms", not how to **remove** those attributes.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested rendering an image using the following code:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Full Logo")
```

and it rendered with the height and width attributes as when using the FieldRenderer in a Webform:

```
<img src="/~/media/images/logos/full-logo.png?h=102&amp;la=en&amp;w=500" alt="Company Logo" width="500" height="102">
```

Comment: We can also add height and width attributes like this
<img src=@Model.Image.Src alt=@Model.Image.Alt width=@Model.Image.Width height=@Model.Image.Height>